# Placeholder within Component not showing in JSS

Tags: jss, placeholders, sxa-jss

I am new to Sitecore `JSS` development. I am really struggling with how placeholders are working in JSS. I am using VUE.JS for my development. I have three root level placeholders in the `layout.vue`. I can see the root level placeholders are working but the placeholder inside my component is not showing the data:

Below is my VUE code for `footer` component:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="component link-list col-8 col-sm-9 col-lg-10 footer-links--major">
     <div class="component-content">
       <placeholder name="jss-footer/jss-top-links" :rendering="rendering" /> //this is not showing 
     </div>
</div>
```

The `LinkList` component code (Not displayed):

```
<template>
  <ul>
    <li class="item0 odd first">
      <div class="field-link">
        <!-- <div> <pre>{{JSON.stringify(rendering) }}</pre> </div> -->
        <a href="/about-us" target=""><span>About us</span></a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="item1 even">
      <div class="field-link">
        <a href="/about-us/careers" target=""><span>Careers</span></a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="item2 odd">
      <div class="field-link">
        <a href="/about-us/news-and-media" target=""><span>News and media</span></a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="item3 even">
      <div class="field-link">
        <a href="/help-contact" target=""><span>Help &amp; Contact</span></a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="item4 odd last">
      <div class="field-link">
        <a href="https://www.abc.com.au/login" target=""><span>My RACQ Account</span></a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <pre> {{JSON.stringify(fields)}} </pre>
  </ul>
  
</template>

<script>
//import { Link } from '@sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-vue';
export default {
  name: 'LinkList',
  components: {
  },
  props: {
    rendering: {
      type: Object,
      default: () => ({}),
    },
    fields: {
      type: Array,
      default: () => ([]),
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

My layout.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <visitor-identification />
    <placeholder name="jss-header" :rendering="route" />
    <div class="container">
      <placeholder name="jss-main" :rendering="route" />
      <placeholder name="jss-footer" :rendering="route" />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { Placeholder } from '@sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-vue';
import VisitorIdentification from './VisitorIdentification';

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import './assets/app.css';

export default {
  name: 'Layout',
  props: {
    route: {
      type: Object,
      default: () => ({}),
    },
    rendering: {
      type: Object,
      default: () => ({}),
    }
  },
  metaInfo() {
    return {
      title:
        (this.route.fields && this.route.fields.pageTitle && this.route.fields.pageTitle.value) ||
        'Page',
    };
  },
  components: {
    Placeholder,
    VisitorIdentification,
  },
};
</script>
```

I am using page designs and partial designs to add footer to the SXA. The footer is added but top links are not below is my sitecore setup:
[image: Footer partial design]

Presentation details for partial design
[image: Presentation details for partial page]

Links not shown:
[image: Links do not appear]

Comment: I haven't used Vue implementation of JSS so far but React one so cannot comment fully but take a look in documentation -> https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/hd/190/sitecore-headless-development/working-with-placeholders-in-a-jss-vue-js-sample-app.html looks like you are missing some definitions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name is `jss-footer/jss-top-links` which means you're using dynamic placeholders. This is what the docs say about them:

https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/hd/190/sitecore-headless-development/sitecore-dynamic-placeholders-and-jss.html

> Dynamic placeholders were introduced with Sitecore 9.0. JSS takes
> advantage of this feature to drive layout and content dynamically in
> JSS applications.
>
> A central part of Sitecore architecture is a data-driven page layout
> based on addressing the location of components using placeholder keys.
>
> Components define their available placeholders in their code/markup
> and are placed according to their defined placeholder on the page.
> Placeholder addresses are usually fully qualified paths, meaning they
> contain the entire hierarchy of placeholders, delimited with a forward
> slash ('/'), much like a URL path
>
> The shortcomings of this system become apparent when you attempt to
> place the same component more than once at the same placeholder
> address.
>
> In the following example layout, it is unclear which Tabs component
> the Tab should be placed in when given the placeholder path
> /phContent/phTab. Out of the box, Sitecore puts a Tab component in the
> first Tabs container.
>
> To solve this problem, placeholder keys must be dynamic. Some possible
> approaches are:
>
> Attach an index to the placeholder key based on the position of the
> component. For example, /phContent/phTab_1.
>
> Utilize the unique identifier (UID) given by Sitecore to a component
> when it is placed on a page. For example,
> /phContent/phTab_8DFE46A3-5D17-43E1-835D-129D18BD59AC.
>
> Some combination of the previous approaches.
>
> The UID approach is the most resilient for scenarios such as moving
> components in advanced Sitecore Editors such as Experience Editor and
> Horizon.

So you should try one of the above approaches to fix the problem.

Also try this:

```
<placeholder name="jss-top-links" :rendering="rendering" />
```

If your placeholder is inside another placeholder you only need the last segment.

Comment: Thanks that solved my issue.